# Comparison of a date with today

Tags: date, google-apps-script

I'm getting a value from a cell in the google sheet. In this example, it's "22/03/2024".

```
// getting the value that I want to test
let jourtestee = sheetRaw.getRange(2,5).getValue().getDate();
let moistestee = sheetRaw.getRange(2,5).getValue().getMonth();
let annéetestee = sheetRaw.getRange(2,5).getValue().getFullYear();
let NewDateTestee = new Date(annéetestee,moistestee,jourtestee,0,0,0)


// getting today date
const d = new Date();
let day = d.getDate();
let month = d.getMonth();
let year = d.getFullYear();
let NewToday = new Date(year,month,day,0,0,0);

console.log(NewToday == NewDateTestee) // true
```

It's working well but I think it's very complicated and I don't need the hour,minute,second. I want to test only if it's the same day

Maybe there is an easier way to do?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString with `getDisplayValue()` is one option.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the date in sheet sis same as today's date.

```
function checkDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // Replace 'Sheet1' with your sheet name
  var cell = sheet.getRange('A1'); // Replace 'A1' with the cell containing the date value

  var cellDate = cell.getValue(); // Get the date value from the cell
  var todayDate = new Date(); // Get today's date

  // Format both dates to compare only the date part (without time)
  var cellDateFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(cellDate, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  var todayDateFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(todayDate, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

  // Compare the formatted dates
  if (cellDateFormatted === todayDateFormatted) {
    Logger.log('The date in cell A1 is the same as today\'s date.');
    // Perform additional actions if needed
  } else {
    Logger.log('The date in cell A1 is not the same as today\'s date.');
    // Perform alternative actions if needed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding rows with today's date

```
function findingRowswithTodaysDate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();//assume data is in column 2
  const dt = new Date();
  const tdv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  let rowwithtodaysdate = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let d = new Date(r[1]);
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf();
    if(dv == tdv) {
      rowwithtodaysdate.push(i + 2)
    }
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rowwithtodaysdate));
}
```